# Unable to connect via JDBC to local SQLExpress

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I´ve just installed a SQLEXpress 2016 instance, but I cannot connect to it via a Java based SQL-Client (squirrel). It works fine through SSMS and .net code though.

It timesout

The connection string I´ve tried are:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=swdb;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=swdb;
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=swdb;
```

I am using the sqljdbc42.jar as the driver.

I am able to connect successfully to other SQL instances (though not SQLEXpress)

I´ve already enabled TCP/IP on the SQL Server configuration manager, as well as the local ip, removing dynamic port and setting the 1433 to it.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded with:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instance=sqlexpress;databaseName=swdb;
```